# Need to show my page prior to parameters in my .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess that is working fine, I just need to add the page name before the parameters

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]


# PRODUCT PAGE IS WORKING GREAT

# NEWS PAGE I AM TRYING TO SHOW THE PAGE NAME

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /morenews\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . morenews/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^morenews/([^/]+)/$ morenews?id=$1 [L]

# THIS ISLEADING TO INTERNATL SERVER ERROR 500 
#http://www.lebmotors.com/new/morenews/12/

# PRODUCT PAGE IS WORKING GREAT
# NEED TO SHOW moreprod before parametsr it is now just website new/1/2/3/4 i ned to make it website/new/moreprod/2/2/3/4

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\?id=([^&\s]+)&topid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\?id=([^&\s]+)&topid=([^&\s]+)&catid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2/%3/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\?id=([^&\s]+)&topid=([^&\s]+)&catid=([^&\s]+)&cagid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2/%3/%4/? [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ moreprod?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ moreprod?id=$1&topid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ moreprod?id=$1&topid=$2&catid=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ moreprod?id=$1&topid=$2&catid=$3&cagid=$4 [L]
```

I am trying to show pagename before paramters

Comment: Provide some examples of your new URL that you want.

Comment: This is now the home: http://www.lebmotors.com/new/index Clicking morenews takes me to http://www.lebmotors.com/new/12/ I want it to take me to http://www.lebmotors.com/morenews/new/12/

Comment: Are you talking about this original link: `http://www.lebmotors.com/new/morenews.php?id=12` on your home page?

Comment: Hello yes, Thank you very much, it is resolved in this manner below, by moving the remove .php extension to the bottom, so it does not affect the above links

Comment: ok glad to know it worked out for you.

Comment: Thank alot, a minor scenario, if file has no parameter,just want to rename, 1st works 2nd doesnt
       RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /rent2\.php\?r=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
       RewriteRule . CarRental/%1/? [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /rent2\.php\?r=([^&\s]+)&w=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
     RewriteRule . CarRental/%1/%2/? [R=301,L]
     RewriteRule ^CarRental/([^/]+)/$ rent2.php?r=$1 [L]
     RewriteRule ^CarRental/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ rent2.php?r=$1&w=$2 [L]
     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /rent\.php\ [NC]
     RewriteRule . RentCar/ [R=301,L]
     RewriteRule ^RentCar/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ rent.php[L]

Comment: rent2.php goes to: 
http://www.lebmotors.com/new/CarRental/moto/Bike/ but rent.php does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, just moved these lines to the bottom of .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /new/
        ....
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
        RewriteRule . moreprod/%1/? [R=301,L]
        .....
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /moreprod\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)&topid=([^&\s]+)&catid=([^&\s]+)&cagid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
        RewriteRule . moreprod/%1/%2/%3/%4/? [R=301,L]
        RewriteRule ^moreprod/([^/]+)/$ moreprod.php?id=$1 [L]
        .....
        RewriteRule ^moreprod/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ moreprod.php?id=$1&topid=$2&catid=$3&cagid=$4 [L]
        # THIS TO THE BOTTOM
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
        RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```